# Ever heard of "dialoginous" as an adjectival form of "dialog"?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, vocabulary, neologisms

Have any of you seen the word "dialoginous" used in academic writing? I am inclined to use it in my dissertation, but am having difficulty finding it anywhere but in a 1965 edition of the *Waterloo Lutheran Cord* at this site: http://scholars.wlu.ca/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1153&context=thecord
(p.11 in the article titled, "Camp Deadwood, Heathen Mills."

I thought that Paolo Freire had used it in *Pedagogy of the Oppressed*, but can't locate it.

Thanks for your input. I like the word as it takes an adjectival form that seems to imply more than the standard "dialogic." I wouldn't mind claiming it a a coined form, but it's not mine originally, based on Cord article. *emphasized text*

Comment: Saying 'Have any of you seen the word "dialoginous" used in academic writing? ... I wouldn't mind claiming it a[s] a coined form' doesn't mean that it actually _is_ an accepted word. And just one example on Google seems to strongly imply that it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

**"dialoginous"** only has one result in Google: http://scholars.wlu.ca/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1153&context=thecord

(just ctrl+f the word to find it)

---

A more standard variant is the word **"dialogous"**, which has about 12,000 Google results:

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dialogous)

> Of or relating to dialogue; that writes or participates in a dialogue.

Comment: Or, I would argue even more standard and commonly used, [_dialogic(al)_](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dialogic). Google Books also [agrees](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dialogous%2Cdialogic%2Cdialogical&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) that those forms are both significantly more common than _dialogous_.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet ~ yes, I didn't include those as OP already mentioned them and it seemed like he wanted something that had "-ous" in it

Comment: Oops, I must have skipped the last paragraph of the question!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word from *Pedagogy of the Oppressed* you are thinking of is “**dialogical**.”

Paulo Friere used many forms of the word dialogue, however “dialogical” the closest adjective form in *Pedagogy of the Oppressed*. Dialogical is used throughout – a total of 18 times, or 20 if you count “antidialogical.” He also uses the adverb “dialogically.”

Take the following examples:

> “Thus, the **dialogical** character of education as the practice of freedom does not begin when the teacher-student meets with the students-teachers in a pedagogical situation, but rather when the former first asks herself or himself what she or he will dialogue with the latter about”
>
> “Faith in people is an *a priori* requirement for dialogue; the “**dialogical** man” believes in others even before he meets them face to face.”

--Paulo Friere, *Pedagogy of the Oppressed*

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dialogic) defines dialogical as a variant of dialogic: of, relating to, or characterized by dialogue.

According to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dialogical), the first known usage was in 1825-35; from Medieval Latin *dialogicus* from Greek *dialogikós*, equivalent to *diálog(os)* dialogue + -*ikos* -ic

“**Dialogical**” (and to an extent, “**dialogic**”) can be found from many academic sources discussing philosophy and education, often referencing Friere’s “theory of dialogical action” and Mikhail Mikhailovich Bakhtin’s concept of “dialogic imagination.” "Dialogical interaction analysis" is based on the works of George Herbert Mead and Bakhtin. In psychology, “Dialogical Self Theory” (DST) was also inspired by this concept.

**Dialoginous** honestly sounds a bit cumbersome to me. The Cord article was also the only example I could find of its usage. However, I do see a potential value in using a unique form of the word to distinguish it from the terms “dialogical” and “dialogic,” which seem to have a number of connotations and associations you may not necessarily want to imply in your dissertation. It depends on your intended meaning. If you find “dialogic” too general, then “dialogous” may be as well. Just think carefully about the meaning you want to convey. If another adjectival form of "dialogue" with precedent and accepted usage fits, I might just go with that to be safe.